# Can console.trace() be implemented "manually"?

Tags: javascript

I'm running JavaScript code in a WebWorker, and there is no implementation of `console`.

I am building my own `console` emulation, and I would like to know if there is a way to emulate `console.trace()`

I have already code that pipes the `console.info()` ... to the "main thread".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass to the main thread `(new Error).stack`. It's a string with a line per step of the stack, analogous to what you get using `console.trace()`.

Comment: Or `Error().stack`, since `Error` can be used as a factory function.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use the explicit `new` : the reader doesn't have to remember (or check) whether the constructor also works as a factory function. That's also why I strongly dislike constructors designed to deal around forgotten `new`.

Comment: I agree and JSHint will also complain about missing `new` because it will not make the difference between these native constructor/factories and custom constructors. I think the worst part of the way most native constructors are designed is that you cannot inherit their logic without using composition. E.g. `Error.call(Object.create(Error.prototype));` would still return a new object.